# Render RGBA to PNG in pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, web-worker

Let's say I have a `canvas` element, and I need to turn the image on the canvas into a PNG or JPEG. Of course, I can simply use `canvas.toDataURL`, but the problem is that I need to do this a twenty times a second, and `canvas.toDataURL` is [extremely slow](http://jsperf.com/canvas-todataurl-imagetype-performance/9) -- so slow that the capturing process misses frames because the browser is busy converting to PNG.

My idea is to call `context.getImageData(...)`, which evidently is much faster, and send the returned `CanvasPixelArray` to a Web Worker, which will then process the raw image data into a PNG or JPEG. The problem is that I can't access the native `canvas.toDataURL` from within the Web Worker, so instead, I'll need to resort to pure JavaScript. I tried searching for libraries intended for Node.js, but [those](https://github.com/pkrumins/node-png) are written in C++. Are there any libraries in pure JavaScript that will render raw image data into a PNG or JPEG?

Comment: So it can not run server side?

Comment: @madflow It would need to send all the data to the server, and since there's a lot of data (20 frames per second for minutes), that wouldn't be ideal.

Comment: O.K. If you have to fallback to a server solution - there is also phantomjs (http://phantomjs.org/) which is designed (as far as I understand) for tasks like this. Sorry - no pure Javascript solution as far as I know.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to send the raw pixel data to your server and convert it to whatever kind of image you need on that end? If toDataURL is slow, I imagine converting things to PNG with plain JS will be even slower...

Comment: @GGG But the key is to use Web Workers, where the slowness isn't experienced by the user.

Comment: @CaseyChu I have a gut feeling that creating a png from raw pixel data  every .05 seconds with JavaScript will result in users experiencing slowness, threads or not... but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Edu See the answer I just posted

Comment: @CaseyChu Please check my comment in your solution. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to write my own PNG encoder, which supports both RGB and palette depending on how many colors there are. It's intended to be run as a Web Worker. I've open-sourced it as [usain-png](https://github.com/bitsofpancake/usain-png).

Comment: I've tried to use it with nodejs (in server side) but it was very very slow.... I have posted my problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648633/nodejs-canvas-to-base64-png-stream   . Do you have any idea that may help? thanks a lot.

Comment: what about rgba?

Answer (score 9):

There have been several JavaScript ports of libpng, including [pnglets](http://elf.org/pnglets/) (very old), [data:demo](http://code.google.com/p/data-demo/source/browse/trunk/modes/png/png.js), and [PNGlib](http://www.xarg.org/2010/03/generate-client-side-png-files-using-javascript/).

The [PNG spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/) itself is pretty straightforward – the most difficult part you may have is with implementing a simple PNG encoder yourself is getting [ZLIB](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1950.txt) right (for which there are also many independent JavaScript implementations out there).

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a C++ to JavaScript compiler called [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten).

Someone made a [port of libpng](https://github.com/hachque-Emscripten/libpng-1.2.49), which you might want to check.