# NODEJS Canvas to base64 png stream

Tags: node.js, canvas, png, base64

Imagine that i have a client that only can read base64 images and i want to show that images like a realtime movie (as less latency as possible).

This images are created on server side using nodejs canvas lib. For each image that i send to the client i see the difference between them with imagediff nodejs lib and i only send the difference match image.

In the client side i show it putting the last image exactly over the previous ones (layers).

The problem is that in server side i have the following values that slow down the process:

1. 16ms: after draw canvas:
2. 42ms: imagediff (imagediff nodejs lib)
3. [100 to 250ms] - toDataUrl (canvas to png base64 - canvas nodejs lib toBuffer().toString('base64'))

The big issue is in 3.

Do you have a different solution for this?

Thanks for your time.

Eduardo

Comment: Are you making a web-based VNC client?

Comment: Im trying to do a canvas server-side applications and show it in a set-top-box "browser" that only can read base64 encode images... like vnc, yes, but with this technology.

Comment: I don't see a whole lot you could cut out from what you have.  There is no way to load a regular image onto the canvas somehow?  You could create those images on the fly from within Node.  Just out of curiosity, what device are you targeting?

Comment: Brad, thanks for your help, so far. Im creating that images on the fly with nodejs with canvas nodejs lib. My problem is the output of that images via socket because the transformation of canvas to base64 is very slow.

Comment: Have you considered sending an image ID via websocket, and then loading the actual image over a persistent HTTP connection out-of-band?  Especially if you keep headers to a minimum, this should be fairly efficient, and will use less bandwidth than base64 encoding the image for in-band transport.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try and comeback to you...

Comment: Ok. So, i continue with the same problem. Passing the canvas object to a real png image takes too long.. i will continue my research.

Comment: This is a bit out there, but what if you displayed an image on top of the canvas, and then draw it on the actual canvas, and then remove the temporary image that was sitting on top of it?  This is more overhead, but maybe the timing will work, depending on what you need to do.  I suspect displaying that image will be much faster than working with the canvas, but you still need the composite in the canvas or you'll have a billion new images stacked on top of each other.

Comment: Brad, the canvas object is on server side. In the client side i have 30 html image objects (the layers) that loads whatever image the server send to it. In order to not have that billion new images on the client, what i do is to send the full image every new 30 images. The other ones i only send the difference between the new one and the previous one. So, my problem is when i generate the image on the server side. After the Canvas object is done i have to pass it to the client as an image. And that process is the one that puts a lot of latency on the process: check nodejs-canvas module. Thanks

Comment: Ha, I thought the canvas was client-side.  Sorry about that, I misunderstood.  Re-reading your question, that is now quite obvious.  Looking at the times for your benchmark, it seems that drawing the canvas isn't a problem, and imagediff isn't either.  The only problem is transfer.  You've eliminated the base64 part of the problem.  Is the remaining problem then generating a tile from the canvas?  And/or network transfer time?  And how long do each of those take, independent of each other?

Comment: The main problem here is really passing the canvas to base64. The time of [3] is the transformation to base64 (before sending to network). The transfer time increases the latency, of course, but that's a problem solved with better internet connection. I believe canvas nodejs module is made in c/c++ so, even if i choose a different language it will not help. Im stucked here. I will read about video streaming.

Comment: Again though, why do you need to convert to base64?  Why not just serve a real image?  You could send some sort of key to the client via your websocket, and then it could request the image over HTTP.  That image data would be sitting in memory, awaiting the request.

Comment: Brad, we have 2 options here after you have the canvas object in the server. 1. Pass the object to png, write it to a file, alert the client saying to download that image, the client starts to download the image. (Meanwhile you are adding at least 20ms in each communication to the client) 2. Pass the object to base64 and send directly to the client. Its much more quicker than the first.

Comment: I am not suggesting writing the PNG to disk... I am suggesting keeping it in memory and returning it directly upon request.  Once an initial HTTP request is made, you can set it to keep-alive, eliminating the overhead of establishing a new TCP connection.  You would have to measure it to see if that overhead would be worth it, but there is a chance it might be.  If you go with the video streaming route, I would suggest experimenting with various codecs.  In general, there are large buffers required for decoding a stream, adding quite a bit of latency.

Comment: Hi Brad. Thanks again for your comments. I found out the function that takes too long. Is from Cairo lib (C) cairo_surface_write_to_png_stream that nodejs canvas plugin use. Im trying to check if there is a way change this function with better performance.

Comment: To break this down further, does Cairo have an option to dump a bitmap or raw data?  If so, how much faster is it?  If the speed problem has to do with compression into PNG, and not reading from the canvas, then maybe it would be possible to use something other than a canvas?  Such as a straight up bitmap in memory with ImageMagick or similar?

Comment: I will work on that. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Brad, just to say to you that i've to stop with this work. Its in pause mode. When i return to it i will comeback to you. Thanks for your help.